# How to handle list dynamically Using reflection and cast returned data to list

Tags: c#, database, list, reflection

When I add a list in instances value and return that list its provides always **duplicate** value. I wanna read data from the database table values. But its first iterations add a single row value, the second time its provides 2nd row value and replaces the  1st list values.

```
var instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
           type.GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(property =>
            {
                property.SetValue(instance,reader[property.Name]);
            });
            list.Add(instance);  
        }
        return list;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each row in `reader` represents a different instance: create a new instance for each row; i.e.

```cs
while (reader.Read())
{
    var instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    // ...
    list.Add(instance);
}
return list;
```